# How to get emojis on emacs 28?

Tags: emacs, emoji

I just hit an incorrect key sequence in emacs 28.2 and, amazingly, I got a selection of emojis to insert in the doc. The problem is that I have no idea what keys I pressed to get this. Does anyone know? I've done lots of searching and only found commands for emacs 29.

This is an out-of-the-box emacs that was installed when I upgraded Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04:
`GNU Emacs 28.2 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.20, cairo version 1.16.0) of 2022-12-09`

Comment: Although this will only be of help the *next* time something like this happens, you can ask Emacs what keys you pressed recently: `M-x recent-keys`. You can also use a `dribble file` but that's more of an elephant gun to help with debugging (search the Emacs manual for `driblble`).

Comment: I driblbled: I meant `dribble` :-)

Comment: can you can `emoji-list` on emacs 28?

Comment: @Rorschach: both `M-x emoji-list` and `C-h a emoji` return nothing.

Comment: @NickD: `M-x recent-keys` doesn't work for me on emacs 28.2; it doesn't seem to be an interactive command. But I can eval `(describe-keys). 

And I think OP would be better served here with `view-lossage`: either `M-x view-lossage`, or `C-h l` (which doesn't clutter up the lossage as much).

Comment: Good points - in particular, `recent-keys` is indeed not `interactive`: it has to be run with `M-: (recent-keys)` - I presume that's what you meant when you wrote `(describe-keys)` which AFAICT does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any emoji fonts install emacs should be able to display it without anything extra. But if you want to insert emojis maybe look into the package *emacs-emojify*. I used [this guide](https://ianyepan.github.io/posts/emacs-emojis/) to set it up in my config.